Converting a simple parametric surface to a function of two variables
I'm looking for a function of two variables that satisfy very specific conditions.
Namely,

$f(x,y) = 1$ if $(x,y)$ is a point on the unit circle,
$f(x,y) = 0$ if $(x,y)$ is a point on an ellipse with semi-major axis $a$ and semi-minor axis $b$
The point $(cos(\theta),sin(\theta),1)$ is connected to the point $(a \cdot cos(\theta), b \cdot sin(\theta), 0)$ by a straight line

This can be more succintly described by the following parametric surface:
$$
x(u,v) = ((1-v) \cdot a + v) cos(u)
$$
$$
y(u,v) = ((1-v) \cdot b + v) sin(u)
$$
$$
z(u,v) = v
$$
in which $u\in[0, 2\pi]$ and $v\in[0,1]$.
Here's how it looks plotted on Desmos 3D. https://www.desmos.com/3d/p2bairyzuo
It's not too hard to find a solution for when $a=b$, since tweaking $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ already gives a cone shape, which can be translated and scaled so that conditions 1 and 2 satisfy. For instance,
$$
f(x,y)=\frac{{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-1}}{1-a}+1
$$
But for the life of me, I couldn't figure out any solution for the general case. I did find a continuous solution that satisfies conditions 1 and 2, but not 3. Which is nice, but not what I'm looking for.
$$
\frac{
    \frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} - 1
}{
    \frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} - \left( x^2 + y^2 \right)
}
$$
If anyone has more experience with parametric equations and multivariable calculus and can help me solve this, that would be greatly appreciated.

You might not be able to get this into a form of $z=f(x,y)$. The whole reason parameterisation exists is because explicit forms can be very difficult or even impossible to write down. It's an interesting surface though, are you using it for a wider problem?

@jonnybolton16 yes, I'm using this for a wider problem. If this has a nice solution, it can be used in computer graphics to render ellipses with a textured stroke of fixed width. I'm afraid there is no good solution, though.

And you're only able to render surfaces if they have an explicit representation?

Not exactly an answer, but I've managed to find an implicit representation of the form $F(x,y,z)=0$:
$$\frac{x^{2}}{\left(a+z\left(1-a\right)\right)^{2}}+\frac{y^{2}}{\left(b+z\left(1-b\right)\right)^{2}} = 1$$
I've combined the implicit forms of an ellipse and a circle, linearly interpolating the semi-major and semi-minor axes so that at $z=0$ they are $a$ and $b$, and at $z=1$ they are both 1.
In order to find an explicit representation of the form $z=f(x,y)$ one now needs to isolate $z$ from the above. Good luck...
Btw you can replace $b$ with $a$ in the above and it's not too difficult to get your $f(x,y)$

Thank you for the help. That does look really tricky, perhaps impossible. I did find another similar representation, but equally (if not even harder) to work with: $x^2(a + az + z)^2 + y^2(b + bz + z)^2 = (a + az + z)^2(b + bz + z)^2$

This is the same expression as mine when you divide both sides by the RHS, and when you collect the $z$ terms together in each bracket

Actually, not quite, but I think you have sign errors as it should be $-az$ and $-bz$

ah, you're right, I copied it wrong. well, I threw this into sympy and it found an answer. but it's 2.5 megabytes long. Guess I'm giving up on this.

Ouch. Hence the beauty of parameterisation!
